# Delay scrolling in scrollView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uikit

Is it possible to delay scrolling in `UIScrollView`? I know, that it is already delayed, but I'd like to increase the time interval of delay. Is there a way to do it without overriding of `handlePan:` of scrollView's `panGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what do you think about "delay scrolling" ? You want to fire the scroll of an UIScrollView after a time delay ?

Comment: @Vincent Saluzzo yes, exactly. I want to move finger without feedback during 1 second, for example, and only after this to start to scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

Create a `DelayGestureRecognizer` class

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface DelayGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer

@end

@implementation DelayGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    });
}

@end
```

Then, when you set up your `UIScrollView`:

```
DelayGestureRecognizer *delayGestureRecognizer = [DelayGestureRecognizer new];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:delayGestureRecognizer];
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:delayGestureRecognizer];
```

(You get the idea... actually, it would probably be better to use a timer and to invalidate the timer in the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `- reset` method, in case the gesture recognizer is called more than once in less than a second...)

Comment: Cool idea. But state is readonly-property, is there a way to set it to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed somehow else?

Comment: oh, sorry, it works with #import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>